# Hughes and Cresswell's definition of consistency

Tags: logic, modal-logic

On page 46 of Hughes and Cresswell's *A New Introduction To Modal Logic*, we have the following definition of consistency.

> **Consistency** :
> We shall say that an axiomatic system is consistent iff
> not every wff is a theorem of that system. In other words, a system is
> inconsistent iff every wff is a theorem.

The definition of consistency strikes me as having clear counterexamples. Consider a system *S* where wffs A, ¬A and ¬P are theorems but P is not. Here we have a contradiction even though not every wff is a theorem of *S*. What am I missing ?

Comment: If we can prove both $A$ and $not A$, the theory is already inconsistent. And then it can prove everything, so also $P$

Comment: In intuitionist logic, it seems problematic, because $\lnot \lnot p$ is not equivalent $p$ there, so we can’t deduce everything, only statements of the form $\lnot p.$ That includes $\lnot\lnot p,$ but the inability to deduce $p$ from here means some statements might not be provable. However, the underlying assumptions of most books is that standard logic (with excluded middle) applies.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Without the excluded middle, no reasonable math is possible to my opinion.

Comment: @Peter What? Plenty of math can be developed purely constructively (and I say this as a classical logician). That's just a bizarre claim.

Comment: @Peter That’s just narrow-minded. It is fascinating to discuss what the excluded middle gives you. It might not be your cup of tea, but there is a lot of fascinating results in intuitionist math, and there is an extent to which you can see the various proofs of set theory independence of axioms using forcing are done by moving to a logic of sets that has no excluded middle, then “booleanizes” that model.

Comment: My favorite example is: Why can’t we write out a discontinuous function without case statements or limits? Because all functions are continuous in intuitionist math, so we need a method method that is not intuitionist to define a discontinuous function. The most simple non-intuitionist way to define a function on the reals is to define the function piecewise.

Comment: @Thomas I’m not sure I understand your first comment. Intuitionistic logic has explosion (though it can be gracefully omitted in a lot of presentations to give minimal logic), but I may be missing your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty much answered in the comments, but the resolution is that there is no such system $S.$ Classical logic has the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), which says that for any sentences $A$ and $B,$ we can infer $B$ from $A$ and $\lnot A.$ How this manifests in deductive systems varies by presentation, but semantically it follows from the fact that $A$ and $\lnot A$ are not simultaneously satisfied in any interpretation, so (vacuously) $B$ holds in any interpretation that satisfies $A$ and $\lnot A.$

Thus H&C's definition of inconsistency is equivalent to the definition that a system is inconsistent if there is a sentence $A$ such that both $A$ and $\lnot A$ are theorems.

Still, it would probably be better to use the other definition, since it is closer to the "idea" of inconsistency, and there are [nonclassical logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic) that aren't explosive, and so the two definitions are not equivalent in these contexts.